# pqyt5 QTableView - drag and drop multiple selected rows simultaneously

Tags: python, qt, drag-and-drop, pyqt5, qtableview

I'm wondering what I need to do to configure a QTableView so that I am able to use shift+click and ctrl+click to select multiple rows **and then drag and drop them within the tableview.**

The code I have at this stage is:

```
class testWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(testWindow,self).__init__()
        self._ui = uic.loadUi('mainwindow.ui', self)
        self.csvTableModel = TableModel()
        self.csvDataTableView.setModel(self.csvTableModel)
        self.csvDataTableView.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.csvDataTableView.verticalHeader().setSectionsMovable(True)       
        self.csvDataTableView.verticalHeader().setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        self.csvDataTableView.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
```

Where the .csvDataTableView object defined in the .ui file is, obviously enough, a QTableView.

This code lets me select rows by clicking on row headers, use ctrl and shift to select multiple rows etc. Where it falls down is when I try to drag and drop.

As soon as I click the button down, the QHeaderView seems to interpret that as me telling it to select/deselect the row represented by the header the mouse is currently over. It will still happily allow me to drag and drop that single row if I move the mouse before releasing the button, but it does nothing with any other selected rows at all other than move them (if required) to make space for the single row that moved or occupy space previously taken up by that row.

I.e. if the original order of row headers was:

1

2

3

4

and I clicked 1, then ctrl clicked 3 and 4, then pressed the mouse button down over 4 and moved it to before where 1 was in an attempt to move the entire selection, the result is:

4

1

2

3

where what I actually wanted to see, and would have seen had the entire selection been moved rather than just row 4 is:

1

3

4

2

I don't know if it's possible to indicate to qt that I want to move **all selected rows, not just the one I was hovering over when I pressed the mouse button down** without actually subclassing QHeaderView and rewriting some of it's functions (although I hope it is).

Assuming that I do need to subclass QHeaderView, would rewriting startDrag to check what rows are selected at that time and dropEvent to move all selection rows, not just the one the mouse was over when the button was pressed, be enough? If so, would this result in the dropIndicator showing the ghost outline of all selected row headers while I'm dragging or just the one?
If not, would I need to reimplement mousePressEvent and mouseMoveEvent [as outlined in the qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/dnd.html) or is there an easier way?